# Memory management for arguments to some Qt functions/constructors?

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I want to add items to a QTreeWidget when a button is pressed. I'm using the following code in my program:

```
void MainWindow::on_training_addButton_clicked()
{
    countertest++;
    QStringList slist;
    slist << QString::number(countertest);
    ui->trainingDataTreeWidget->addTopLevelItem(new QTreeWidgetItem(slist)); //case 1

    //QTreeWidgetItem* item = new QTreeWidgetItem(slist); //case 2
    //ui->trainingDataTreeWidget->addTopLevelItem(item);
    //delete item;
}
```

In both cases I allocated dynamic memory for a QTreeWidgetItem. In the second case, I deleted it after passing it to `addTopLevelItem()`, but I'm worried Qt might need it later. What's the proper way to go about this?

Comment: As far as I know, once you add an item to a tree widget like that the tree widget owns it and will delete it when the tree widget is deleted.  You shouldn't delete it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have another question.. If I use the second case without the `delete item` and the button is pressed again, the data that `item` points to gets overwritten, right? So will it affect the contents of the QTreeWidget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QTreeWidget destructor will take care of the deletion, and hence the class the life-cycle of the items. Just drop your external delete. IT would cause QTreeWidget trying to delete a dangling pointer, which would be the well-known double deletion crash.

Here is the proof from the documentation as well as the source:

#### Documentation

> [QTreeWidget::~QTreeWidget()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#dtor.QTreeWidget)
>
> Destroys the tree widget and all its items.

#### Source

```
/*!
  \internal

  Destroys this tree model.
*/

QTreeModel::~QTreeModel()
{
    clear();
    delete headerItem;
    rootItem->view = 0; 
    delete rootItem;
}

/*!
  \internal

  Removes all items in the model.
*/

void QTreeModel::clear()
{
    SkipSorting skipSorting(this);
    beginResetModel();
    for (int i = 0; i < rootItem->childCount(); ++i) {
        QTreeWidgetItem *item = rootItem->children.at(i);
        item->par = 0; 
        item->view = 0; 
        delete item;
    }    
    rootItem->children.clear();
    sortPendingTimer.stop();
    endResetModel();
}
```